# Wordpress order by query in wp_postmeta

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

Here's the thing

I have some issues with my `query` to get the `meta_value` ordered by `desc`.
but it not working the way i wanted .
[image: Take look at the meta_value]

[image: Take look at the meta_value here too]

what did i wrong ?
i tried to get the meta_query by order desc
it should be

```
meta_value =>
108
59
5
4
2
0
0
```

Comment: ORDER BY meta_value + 0

Comment: @Strawberry , thats work ! just , can you send it as an answer and write some explanation bout why is that works ?

Comment: This is such a trivial issue, I think it unworthy of such a canonical response. The data type is varchar, so you're comparing strings instead of integers, hence '5..','4..','3..', etc. Adding 0 (or indeed any number) to the string implicitly converts it to an integer.

Comment: I totally knew that ! i was completely sure that the issue have something to do with data type , but i didnt know how to convert the `string` comparison with `integer`. very thankful :) @Strawberry

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT *
FROM 'wp_postmeta'
WHERE meta_key = 'post_views_count'
ORDER BY meta_value DESC
```

It's pretty much correct, but it might be the apostrophe around the met_key and meta_value that's not being recognized. If it's just under one table, it should be fine. I tried something similar on my wordpress mysql workbench, and noticed that the query isn't recognized when I placed apostrophe around 'meta_key' and 'meta_value' (order didn't work and didn't pull up the correct values). When it was removed, it worked fine.

Comment: The blind leading the blind

Comment: @Strawberry why do you say that ?

Comment: Because ['] denotes a string. [`] denotes a table/column and is largely redundant. Further, I doubt that any problem that the OP is having is in any way connected to their use of backticks or inverted commas.